# HDF gzip compression vs. ASCII gzip compression

Tags: c, gzip, hdf5

I have a 2D matrix with 1100x1600 data points. Initially, I stored it in an ascii-file which I tar-zipped using the command

```
tar -cvzf ascii_file.tar.gz ascii_file
```

Now, I wanted to switch to hdf5 files, but they are too large, at least in the way I am using them... First, I write the array into an hdf5-file using the c-procedures

```
H5Fcreate, H5Screate_simple, H5Dcreate, H5Dwrite
```

in that order. The data is not compressed within the hdf-file and it is relatively large, so I compressed it using the command

```
h5repack --filter=GZIP=9 hdf5_file hdf5_file.gzipped
```

Unfortunatelly, this hdf file with the zipped content is still larger than the compressed ascii file by a factor of 5, see the following table:

```
file               size
--------------------------
ascii_file         5721600
ascii_file.tar.gz   287408
hdf5_file          7042144
hdf5_file.gzipped  1117033
```

Now my question(s): Why is the gzipped ascii-file so much smaller and is there a way to make the hdf-file smaller?

Thanks.

Comment: Reading a [random `man` page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/h5repack.1.html) suggests `h5repack` does not merely *compress* the data but preserves object layout as well, for fast retrieval. Plain ZIPping does not do that.

Comment: hmm, I guess I just expected that this should not make such a huge difference. In addition, I just found out that using the `--filter=SHUF` option helps to reduce the size to `730156`. Still a factor of 2.5. Any other comments?

Comment: You may only have a few digits per point in the ASCII file, whereas HDF5 is storing a data type for each number, likely a double depending on how you wrote it.  That will definitely take more space.

Comment: @MarkAdler this seems to be a good point, I have not thought about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, after reading [Mark Adler's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180620/mark-adler) comment, I realized that this question is somehow stupid: In the ascii case, the values are truncated after a certain number of digits, whereas in the hdf case the "real" values ("real" = whatever precision the data type has I am using) are stored.

There was, however, one possibility to further reduce the size of my hdf file: by applying the shuffle filter using the option

```
--filter=SHUF
```